# Admob Banner & Smart Banner ads fills entire screen on load

Tags: android, admob, fragment, ads

I am using Smart_Banner and BANNER ads in my android app.

When ad loads for the first time or when the ad changes there is a flash covering the entire screen. This is very irritating to the user. What is the reason and how can I resolve this?

My implementation is based on Fragments. All relevant code is shown below.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Add fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backcolor"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/BANNERAD_UNIT_ID">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

```
  public class AdFragment extends Fragment {

    private AdView mAdView;

    public AdFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        try {
            mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
            
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                   .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.adfragment, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Main Layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_fake"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fragment"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_ad"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_ad"
        class="com.controllers.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the tag closed accidently after ads:adUnitId="@string/BANNERAD_UNIT_ID">

Comment: can you also paste the code for inflating the fragment

Comment: Main Layout code shown at last is inflating it on Main Activity. There is no code inflating it.

Answer (score 0):

I added the second line to set the layout height. Which resolved my issue.
I am not sure if this is the best solution but it seems to be working on my phone at least.

```
  mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
  mAdView.getLayoutParams().height = com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getHeightInPixels(getActivity());
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                   .build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```